# Questions about .Net inheritance

Tags: c#, .net

```
public class Father
{
  // static string TYPE = "FATHER";
    public Father()
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("ctor");
    }
    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm father");
    }
}

public class Son:Father
{
    public override void Print()
    {
        base.Print();
        Console.WriteLine("I'm son");
    }
}
```

As we konw, if we call Son.Print(),It'll print out "I'm father" and "I'm son".And  Father.Print() is an instance method ,we need to create an instance first.So that's the question,**who creates it**?Obviously,not me...
Or Son owns **two** Print methods in the methodtable.One of them can be accessed by Father,anthor can be accessed by itself?
Which one is right?Or neither is right?Please tell me!Thanks!

Comment: Minor quibble, but Son : Father is a really bad example of inheritance in its OOP sense

Comment: If you access class Son as a Son type, you get both the class Father and class Son data and behaviors.

Comment: Indeed, the example itself is probably what's causing the confusion and not inheritance in general. `Son` is printing both statements because in this case a `Son` _is_ a `Father`.  While that holds true for a segment of the population, it's certainly not universally true as implied by this inheritance hierarchy. `Son` and `Father` should be interfaces, not inheriting classes. Each `Person` entity should implement the appropriate interfaces. This is a great example of how not to use inheritance. (Though I'm sure there's a good "inheritance" joke in here somewhere regarding a father and son...)

Comment: I always use `Shape`, `Square`, and `Triangle` as everyone can understand that squares are shapes and triangles are shapes but triangles and squares are different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Who creates it? Obviously not me

What makes you so sure? Of course you do:

```
Son s = new Son();
```

> Or `Son` owns two `Print` methods in the methodtable.

No, it has just one `Print` method, but it has something else: it knows about its base class, `Father`, which has its own `Print` method. That's why `Son` has access to two `Print`s - its own and his `Father`'s.

Comment: Also to clarify. When you don't put anything after the constructor there is a implicit `: base()` added to the end of it. So `Son` is calling `Father`'s parameter-less constructor, and `Father` is calling `object`'s parameter-less constructor (because if you don't specify a parent class a implicit `: object` is added to your class definition).

Comment: Thank you! I know when we call Son's constructor ,it also calls its base's constructor.But who owns its base's reference or who stores the reference ,the keyword base(Sorry,It's wrong,but I don't know how to explain...)?

Comment: There is no reference to base, only *knowledge about* the base. That mysterious "knowledge" usually comes in the form of a reference to the virtual table of the base class, but the standard does not say that it must be that way.

Comment: I'm confused..."There is no reference to base",but how can we call its instance method?

Comment: @LyonGu You need two things to call an instance method - a reference to the object, and a pointer to the method. Because of the way the inheritance is implemented, you can pass a reference of a derived type to a method from its base class. That's why a reference to the base is not necessary: a reference to `this` is sufficient.

Comment: And Son has already overridden his base's Print method,means it doesn't own base's Print anymore.

Comment: @LyonGu It has base's entire virtual table, which has base's `Print`. So it knows how to get to both `Print`s: one in its own vtable, and the other in its base's vtable.

Comment: It makes sense.Thank you!Last question:which difference between virtual table and method table?

Comment: @LyonGu You don't need to add `@<name>`, authors of the answers always get comment notifications. "Virtual table" is a common shorthand for ["Virtual Method Table"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).

Comment: Thank you so much!Best wishes!